# Composite or Single-Field Clustering Key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, clustered-index

My DBA and I are having a disagreement on index structure.

**Consider data for a medical claim...**

We have the `Header` table with fields like:

`ClaimId (varchar(50)), PaidAmount, MemberID...`

and for each header we have one or more records in `Detail` like:

`ClaimId (varchar(50)), LineNumber (smallint), MemberId...`

*The efficiency of the structure or duplication of the data is outside the parameters of this question.*

There are additional tables that tie back to individual `Detail` lines by `ClaimId, LineNumber`, and we frequently `JOIN` `Detail` and `Header` on `ClaimId` as well.

For the `Detail` table, which would be preferable for the clustered index key:

`ClaimId`

or

`ClaimId, LineNumber`

`ClaimId` alone is NOT unique, but the combination of `ClaimId, LineNumber` is unique for a `Detail` record.

One of us believes that `ClaimId` alone is a better clustered key because it is narrower, and that the lookup will be just as efficient since we need to know the `ClaimId` before we lookup the `LineNumber`.

The other believes that the combination of the two is better because it removes the need for an additional `RowID`, and can be used in `JOIN`ing to the support tables that need the `LineNumber` as a `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is bollocks:

> ... ClaimId alone is a better clustered key because it is narrower

because of this

> ClaimId alone is NOT uniquej

A non-unique clustered index will add a 4 byte uniquifier to remove ambiguity of ClaimId because it is the *clustered* index. Why? One reason is all NC indexes refer to it: so how to know ClaimId is which?

It was demonstrated (some time ago, maybe not valid now and can't find it) that non-unique clustered indexes break when you exhaust 2^32 values of the 4 byte uniquifier

Edit :

Question states ClaimId is **not** unique so assumed that uniqifier exists. No need to comment that it may not exist in the context of the question

Comment: For the sake of argument, how is that worse than having a 4 byte int as  the second clustering key?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's definitely not unique.  The nature of the data is we get multiple lines per ClaimID for the detail record, one per incident of service.  So for an ER visit there would be a line for every service provided, but only one header record for the whole thing

Comment: Do note that the uniquifier is _only_ added when necessary. That is, as long as ClaimId is unique, no extra space will be taken. Depending on the cardniality of ClaimId, it may be perfectly fine to use it as the clustering key! Saturating the number of uniquifiers requires you to have 2^31-1 (SQL Server doesn't use unsigned integers in column types) non-unique ClaimId values, which I'd assume is highly unlikely.

Comment: It was stated that ClaimId is not unique.  So this is the assumption made

Comment: There is no business reason why LineNumber is relevant except for being a sequence. Even, then, the user could choose a different sort order. I see no performance advantage either way. In such situation, I would rather opt NOT to have the LineNumber that introduces limitations when adapting to future sql server enhancement.